# Radial function derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ be a function only depending on the distance from the origin, $f = f(r)$, where $r = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$.

I calculated

$$ \Delta f = {n-1\over r}f_r + f_{rr}$$

and I am trying to determine which $f$ satisfy

$${n-1\over r}f_r + f_{rr}=0$$

Clearly for constant functions $\Delta f = 0$. Then my idea was that if $f_r = \log r$ then $f_{rr}={1\over r}$ but this doesn't help.

> How to find non-constant $f$ with $\Delta f = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that

$$-\frac{f_{rr}}{f_r} = \frac{n-1}{r}$$

Integrating, we have $f_r = Cr^{1-n} $ and integrating again, $f = C_1r^{2-n} + C_2$

Comment: Thank you for your help. What happens to ${f_{rr}\over f_r}$ if I integrate it? Does it become ${f_r\over f}$? I have never integrated an expression like this before.

Comment: Explicitly if you integrate we have $-\ln f_r = (n-1)\ln r + K$. Make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. How do you justify dividing by $f_r$? It's clear to me that $f_r$ is not everywhere zero because we assume $f$ is not constant but it could still be zero in some places. Right?

Comment: Have you taken a course in ODEs? The solution to this equation with two initial conditions is unique. So even if steps in the process use a condition that restricts generality, the form of solution we have here has two degrees of freedom with the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. Hence it is the general solution.

Comment: No, I have never taken a course in ODEs...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You might try $f(r)=r^k$, plug that in and see if there is a $k$ that works.